# Find differences in datatables with linq when datatables have different columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

The following function returns the differences of two datatables, but only works if both of the tables have the same columns.

In my case, the columns are different, but column "dictkey". Column "dictkey" exists in both of my datatables.

How I get it to work, that my function returns only rows, where "dictkey" is different respectivly not existent regardless of the other columns.

```
 Public Function Check_Desparity(Byval dtTestStep as DataTable, Byval dtLimits as DataTable) as IEnumerable(Of DataRow)

    Dim diff = dtLimits.AsEnumerable.Except(dtTestSteps.AsEnumberable, DataRowComparer.Default)

    Return diff

    End Function
```

Comment: You need to actually write a loop yourself. Think about how you would do it if it was a manual process. That's how you would do it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `IEqualityComparer` that only compares on the column needed and use the `Except` that takes an `IEqualityComparer` as an argument or you can use `ExceptBy` from MoreLINQ, or you could do your own `ExceptBy` equivalent:

```
Public Function Check_Desparity(Byval dtTestSteps As DataTable, Byval dtLimits As DataTable) As IEnumerable(Of DataRow)
    Dim dtTestStepsHash As New HashSet(Of String)(dtTestSteps.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(dr) CType(dr("dictkey"), String)))
    Return dtLimits.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(dr) Not dtTestStepsHash.Contains(CType(dr("dictkey"),String)))
End Function
```

I assumed column `dictkey` was of type `String`, but you can just put in the correct type.

This functions as an `ExceptBy` operation.

The first line in the function creates a `HashSet` of all the `"dictkey"` values you want to exclude from the answer, because `HashSet` provides an efficient (near-constant) speed `Contains` operation.

The second line returns those rows from the `dtLimits` `DataTable` that have a `"dictkey"` value that is not contained in the `dtTestSteps` `DataTable`, as determined by checking in the `dtTestStepsHash` for each row (`dr`) and excluding those values that are in the `HashSet`.

Comment: This solution works, but I would appreciate a short explanation, because I dont really understand it.

Comment: @ManfredSinger I added an explanation. Let me know if it isn't clear!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation